# Total number of roots of $f(x)=g(x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f(x)$ be non positive continuous function and $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t) dt,\forall x\geq 0$ and $f(x)\geq cF(x)$ where $c \gt 0$ and let $g:[0,\infty]\to R$ be a function such that $\frac{d}{dx} g(x)< g(x),\forall x>0$ and $ g(0)=0$

The question is to find the total number of roots of $f(x)=g(x)$

Since $f(x)$ is a non positive function it implies that $F(x)$ is a decreasing function also F(0)=0 implies $F(x)\leq 0$.So $f(0)=0$ from $f(0)\geq cF(0)$ and the condition that $f$ is non positive. I couldn't proceed after this.Any ideas?

Comment: By $\frac{g(x)}{dx} < g(x)$ you mean $\lim{d\rightarrow 0} \frac{g(x+d)}{d}<g(x) $ ?

Comment: @Lerigorilla sorry it was a typo.edited